# Joomla frontend not loading after upgrading to 3.5

Tags: front-end

Yesterday I upgraded my joomla site from 3.4 to 3.5 .

From then I can access the backend but nothing shows up in the frontend.

How can I troubleshoot it?

Thanks

Comment: Updates should always be tested locally before applying. Joomla 3.5 has some fairly big code changes, which extension developers may need to apply to their extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Spiros and welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange!

It's possible that one or more of the extensions you are using are not yet Joomla 3.5.0 compatible.

I recommend logging in to the back end and setting `System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting` to "Maximum" and refreshing the front-end to see if any meaningful error messages are displayed. This may help you determine which extension is causing the issue.

If this doesn't help, update all third party extensions to the latest versions and try again.

You may need to check the developer website for each extension to verify the extensions are ready for Joomla 3.5.0.

If any of the extensions are not ready for Joomla 3.5.0 yet, you may need to restore your website back to the previous version before you updated to Joomla 3.5.0 (assuming you have a backup) or temporarily remove or disable the offending extension(s) in the meantime.

Also see [What is an efficient way to troubleshoot a “white screen of death”](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/299/120) for other tips on troubleshooting a blank front-end.

Comment: You can also check if an extension is compatible yet in "List of Joomla! Extensions Supporting Joomla! 3.5 and PHP 7" at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJj02l3ByBvJF-Q67XXuGmrFvS8iIBEnDEcVcmwqzLc/edit#gid=0

Comment: You're quite welcome, mate... :-)