# Can't decode form data as json after jinput->post->getArray() if some file is chosen

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput, jmail

I retrieve all the form data with:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$formData = new JRegistry($jinput->post->getArray());
```

then decode it and convert to my custom array with:

```
$formDataAsJson = json_decode($formData);
$arrayOfFields = array();
foreach($formDataAsJson as $name => $value) {
    if(!empty($value) && $name !== 'submit') {
        $arrayOfFields[] = '<strong>'.$name.'</strong>: '.$value;
    }
}
```

and then email with:

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
...
$mailer->setBody(implode('<br/>',$arrayOfFields));
```

At my form there is one input with `type="file"` and all the code works if I don't touch this input and fill only inputs with `type="text"` and check inputs with `type="radio"`. However, if I choose a file by using input `type="file"`, the code stops working and I don't receive an email.

If I choose some file but send `$formData` as JSON without decoding it and converting to an array e.g. with:

```
$mailer->setBody($formData);
```

then I receive an email. At that, there is no name for my input `type="file"` inside of JSON line.

So it looks like the input `type="file"` is not being pushed to the JSON line, but why does the code stop working in this case? This is strange. How can I decode form data, convert it to my array and send an email even if I choose a file? Or how to exclude input `type="file"` from `->post->getArray()`?

The code for uploading and sending a file:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$file = $jinput->files->get('nameOfFileInput');
if(!empty($file['name'])) {
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
    $src = $file['tmp_name'];
    $dest = JPATH_SITE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "tmp" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
    if(JFile::upload($src, $dest)) {
        $mailer->addAttachment($dest);
    }
}
```

Joomla 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get file input data with this:

```
$files = $input->files->get('inputName');
```

You don't have to use `JRegistry` and then `json_decode` it. You will get `array` from `$jinput->post->getArray()` in first place.

So your code could be

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$formData = $jinput->post->getArray();
$arrayOfFields = array();
foreach($formData as $name => $value) {
    if(!empty($value) && $name !== 'submit') {
        $arrayOfFields[] = '<strong>'.$name.'</strong>: '.$value;
    }
}
```

But about the problem with filling file input, it should work either way.

File input is not included in `$jinput->post->getArray()`, therefore the problem relies somewhere else.

I suggest you to turn on error reporting, to see if any errors are thrown. You can see how it's done in [this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/304/3944). First point should do it, depending on your server configuration.

Also, you can wrap your code into try-catch, to catch any thrown errors.

```
try {
    // Your code here
    // Create arrayOfFields and send email 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Let me know how it will go.

Comment: Yes, you was right: `$formData` is an array and I can retrieve it without `new JRegistry()`. But a letter still is not being sent if I choose some file and I don't get any error with catch `(Exception $e)` or with maximum Joomla error reporting. At that the file for sending is being uploaded successfully to destination folder.

Comment: Okay. So it seems that uploading a file causes this. Please show some more code and try to move file uploading after sending email. If it sends this way, then it's definately file uploading what causes this.

Comment: But uploading and sending a file both are ok if I send `$formData` as JSON with `new JRegistry()`. And are not ok only if I try send it as an array. I mean when choosing a file. I added more code to the question. How can I move the file after uploading?

Comment: Seeing your code, don't move anything. Did you added file uploading to try-catch block? Is file uploaded correctly?

Comment: Oh, I got it. It's my fault. I have a few forms on my page and all the while I was testing only one of them. It has only field for email and for file. Email I remove from the array before sending (because it's in the header) and file as you said is not included in the array so the form was not sending for the array was empty. Now everything is ok. Thank you for your help!