# White screen of death

Tags: joomla-3.x, search

I do have a weird issue with my Joomla 3.6 page.
All works fine except the search. It works with several words but unfortunately it stops working with a total white blank page (even no HTML-markup).

I tryed debugging like [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/299/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-troubleshoot-a-white-screen-of-death) with no solution. There is no entry in my error.log. My access.log shows me

```
[27/Jul/2016:15:21:28 +0200] "GET /suche?searchword=edi&searchphrase=all&limit=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 430 "/suche?searchword=vendoc&ordering=newest&searchphrase=all&limit=20" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

Nothing special so far. It only appears to happen to certain words (no offensive words).

**EDIT:**

Under "plugins" there is just the "content" and "contact" enabled. If I disable "content" then everything works just fine. Under "components" -> "search" search statistic is logged with state enabled.

Comment: White screen means there is a PHP error but you have error reporting turned off. In your Global Configuration, set `error reporting` to `development`, then report back the error you get when trying again

Comment: @Lodder no error is reported and it is just on random words

Comment: Are you using search or smart search?  If smart search, do you have gather statistics enabled?  Are you using any search filters?

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey where can I find out which one is used? Under components "statistic" is enabled everything else disabled. Under plugins there is just "content" and "contacts" enabled. If I disable "content" everything works just fine. So the issue has to be related under "content"

Comment: From your edit, you are using regular Search.  Any change when disabling statistics?  Since your error_log is empty, you might want to check that your php.ini is set to write to it.

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey with disabled statistic same problem... My error.log is writable there are entries in there - but not for the search, so php.ini isn't that problem.

As I can see the statistic-counter is incremented - it seems "just" a view-issue

Comment: Can you try setting up an alternate page using Components->Smart Search?  This might help narrow down whether it is a code problem or server/resource problem.

Comment: Thank you @YellowWebMonkey this seems to be a code problem ... with smart search the search does work! Very strange behaviour but it may be related to an old template (ja_ores).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try setting up an alternate page using Components->Smart Search? This might help narrow down whether it is a code problem or server/resource problem.

If it is a code problem, check your template's override folder (/templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_search/) to see if there is a template override causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is caused by your script timing out on certain words, or your memory limit being exceeded on certain words (because they are in so many entries). I suggest you increase the PHP memory limit in your `php.ini` and see if that solves the problem. If it doesn't, then try increasing your PHP timeout in your `php.ini`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a timeout. My memory limit is at 128MB and timeout on 60s.

Comment: Double your memory limit to 256MB and check if that solves the problem.

Comment: no changes happening - even when increasing to 512MB

Comment: Are you sure that your changes are taking effect? Also, are you on a VPS or on a shared host?

Comment: It's my machine and changes take affect - yes. I can override via .htaccess. I inserted the memory limit on first line then i made an echo on phpinfo - so yes it tells me 256MB

Answer (score 0):

This solved the Joomla White screen of death for me:

in: `plugins/content/phocagalleryslideshow/phocagalleryslideshow.php`
add the line:

```
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

just before:

```
if (! class_exists('PhocaGalleryLoader')) {
    require_once( JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_phocagallery'.DS.'libraries'.DS.'loader.php');
```

I got a hint that this module was causing the problems by setting in 
`configuration.php` the error reporting to maximum.

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
```